# Помощь в решении Puzzle Captcha(Слайдер капча)

Tags: python, captcha

Занимаюсь парсингом сайтов и часто сталкиваюсь с этой капчей. Хочу найти либо её решение, либо метод для её обхода, возможно как-то куки передавать правильно. Использую не обычные реквест запросы, а через cloudscraper.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/articles/508690/